# Appengine java - Jersey/Jackson JaxbAnnotationIntrospector NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, jersey

I'm re-asking an unanswered question from the now read-only google groups App Engine for Java because I have the exact same problem. ([original](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine-java/uImBt6fOhww/discussion%20original))

I have put together a simple json REST service using jersey, jaxb and jackson. It works *almost* fine, however the ***first*** request to the server always ends up with the exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/xc/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector

For some reason gae/jersey cannot find this class on the initial request. However, all subsequent requests after this work fine, the class then seems to have been loaded.

For additional info:

I'm sending json to the server - in chrome's inspector I can see:

```
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Request Payload {"stuff":["a","b"],"number":"10"}
```

and the relevant resource signature looks like this:

```
  @POST
  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public void run(Params params){};
```

Any help very gratefully received!

EDIT: Here's the full stack trace

```
WARNING: Error for /backtest
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/xc/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(MapperConfigurator.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._setAnnotations(MapperConfigurator.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:609)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:404)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$VoidOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:166)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:895)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:843)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:804)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 60 more
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I can tell you most likely don't have the [optional XC](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) Jackson lib.

The XC package allows you to use Xml Annotations (JAXB) in addition to the Jackson Annotations for mapping classes.

From what I can tell this error will only happen once during Jackson first setup so unless you need JAXB support just ignore the issue.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little embarrassed - adding the dependency does fix the problem and I don't know why I didn't test it before! It's curious though, I'm not using jaxb myself (although I think the guy with the original question was) so I don't see why it should have been required on the class path. It's not something that I could simply ignore either, because it causes the initial request to the app engine instance to fail (which could obviously happen a lot on a low traffic app engine site). Anyway, thanks for the help.