# AppEngine and Jackson Class Not Found: JaxbAnnotationIntrospector (at first)

Tags: json, google-app-engine, jersey, jackson

I'm trying to get a simple AppEngine working that serves as webservices and will delivery content in JSON format.

I'm using Jersey an Jackson, although when I launch the app and access one of the webservices for the first time I get this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/codehaus/jackson/xc/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector

If I try to access another WS right after (or try to re-access the current one) then everything seems to go fine. Just not the first time.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Kr,

Dirk

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appengine java - Jersey/Jackson JaxbAnnotationIntrospector NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860142/appengine-java-jersey-jackson-jaxbannotationintrospector-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I use jackson-xc-1.9.12.jar and the error on first call is still there.